# In the bootstrap button documentation, how are the margins between buttons achieved

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

This not a basic question about "margins" with bootstrap etc. I know how to use both margins and how to use bootstrap.

I am specifically wondering how, in the example I'm providing in Bootstrap documentation, are they are achieving their margins. I don't see them adding margins or using a flexbox or some other spacing method. I must be overlooking something but I don't know what.

Can someone help explain how they are doing it? 
Documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/buttons/

Visual: 
[image: Bootstrap buttons with margins, but how?]

Comment: This is because they are inline block elements. So the gaps are just inline gaps. They don't mention this but their buttons have been inline block elements since the beginning.

Comment: @joshmoto ah! Yes, I actually didn't know that inline and inline-block elements have gaps that act as "mini-margins." Very interesting! Any idea how to control the gap size?

Thank you!

Comment: They only have a gap because the code is on a new line or single html space exists between each button.

Comment: Did you see my answer?

Answer (score 0):

See this codeply demo below on how to control inline block button spacing in bootstrap 4.

https://www.codeply.com/go/Vaen7GzvNF

Make the gaps bigger using Bootstrap utility margin-right `.mr-*` classes

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mr-1">.mr-1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mr-2">.mr-2</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success mr-3">.mr-3</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger mr-4">.mr-4</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning mr-5">.mr-5</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">no class</button>
```

Remove gaps by making sure there is no gaps between button html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Secondary</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Warning</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button>
```

You can also use comment tags `<!-- -->` to strip the gaps between the buttons if you wana keep it tidy, or use php

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button><!--
    --><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Secondary</button><!--
    --><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button><!--
    --><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button><!--
    --><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Warning</button><!--
    --><button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button>
```